# How to remove duplicate values from PHP array based on part of string

Tags: php, arrays, unique

I have a text file in the form of `Name@Phone\n`. I put the data into an array with `explode()`. How can I remove duplicate lines (values) based on Phone only? I want to avoid

```
Eddie@999-999-999
Ed@999-999-999
```

I want to make this unique based on the Phone.

Comment: do you need to keep the "Ed" and "Eddie" information?

Comment: No just to keep one of the records is OK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?php
$result = array();
foreach($dataset as $input):
    $parts = explode('@', $input);
    $result[$parts[1]] = $parts[0];
endforeach;
$result = array_flip($result);
```

Comment: This also worked well for trying to find the newest directory for each day where there are multiple directorys with YYYY-MM-DD-HH-MM-SS as the format.  I used `$directories[$directory] = substr($directory,0,10);` so that the date would end up being the key and the largest numbered time is the last to be created.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't care about the names and just want a list of unique numbers you can replace all characters in the listings that aren't numbers or dashes then do an array_unique():

```
$arr = array(
  'Eddie@999-999-999',
  'Ed@999-999-999'
);

$arr = preg_replace('/[^\d\-]/', '', $arr);
$arr = array_unique($arr);

print_r($arr);
```

If you know the numbers are always in that format (name@number) then the response from @Kenaniah works well.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
$result = array();
foreach($arrayData as $data){
    $uniqueKey = strstr($data, '@');//@999-999-999
    $result[$uniqueKey] = $data;
}

var_dump( $result );
```